# user write debug data to root owned file

Tags: bash, permissions, redirection

I'm running GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) on a Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria system.

I'll be grateful if anyone can explain this for me as I haven't been able to find any documentation which does.
Everything is working as I would like it to but I don't know what mechanism allows 'user' to write to 'root' files without permission.

I'll be happy to provide further documentation if needed.

Synopsis:

- anacron invokes 'foo' as 'root' and redirects 2>&1 to create/overwrite a debug file
- 'root' invocation of 'foo' calls 'runuser' to invoke 'foo' as 'user' redirecting 2>&1 to create/overwrite or append a debug file
- it doesn't matter whether the 'runuser' redirection is to the same file or a different file
- it doesn't matter whether the 'runuser' redirection creates/overwrites or appends to the file
- the output file from the anacron/runuser redirection is owned by 'root' - permissions '0644')
- 'root' invocation of 'foo' exits, having written to the debug file which it owns
- 'user' invocation of 'foo' runs, appends/overwrites the debug file which 'root' owns
- 'user' invocation of 'foo' exits, having written to the debug file which 'root' owns
- Invoking 'foo' as 'user' and redirecting to the 'root' owned debug file in a Terminal session gets "Permission denied"

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

- Ownership and mode matter when a process tries to open a file.
- A redirection like in `foo >logfile` is performed (i.e. `logfile` is opened) by a shell before `foo` starts. The shell forks, the forked copy opens the file and replaces itself with `foo`.
- It's common for a child process to inherit copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors; this includes stdin, stdout, stderr.
- `runuser`, `su` or `sudo` can run something as another user. Such or similar tool may deliberately close some file descriptors, but in general at least stdin, stdout and stderr are inherited.
- A process can duplicate a descriptor without re-opening the corresponding file. A redirection like in `foo 2>&1` is like that, it's performed by the shell before `foo` starts, but this time the file (i.e. whatever the stdout is) has already been opened.

In your "anacron case" whatever process opened the file, it was a process acting as root. The final, non-elevated instance of `foo` was able to use the file because it inherited a copy of the relevant file descriptor.

In case of invoking `foo` as a regular user from a non-elevated shell, there is no elevated process that could open the file and possibly let its non-elevated children inherit copies of the descriptor.